# Set SQLAlchemy PickleType Column Size

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to save a python list to an SQL table in a `PickleType` column which is defined in the class object as `text = Column(PickleType)`. When I try to commit a longer entry I get the following error: `(DataError) (1406, "Data too long for column 'text' at row 1")`. However, SQLAlchemy PickleType [documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/types.html#sqlalchemy.types.PickleType) says nothing about how to set the size of the column. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can try `LargeBinary(length=65536)` to create a `MediumBlob`

Answer (score 0):

PickleType uses a non-lengthed text type to store the data. The error you're getting is probably related to the DBAPI driver you're using, which likely has some configurable limits on large objects, e.g. you're probably using cx_oracle or pyodbc with SQL server.   Check with the DBAPI and the underlying connectivity features in order to configure the max size of a single field that can be sent.

Answer (score 0):

If using **flask-sqlalchemy** you can edit the migration file and change `PickleType()` to `LargeBinary(length=65536)` for example.

| Column Type | Type of BLOB | Max Data that can be stored |
| --- | --- | --- |
| LargeBinary(length=254) | TINYBLOB | Up to 255 bytes |
| LargeBinary() | BLOB | Up to 64 Kb |
| LargeBinary(length=65536) | MEDIUMBLOB | Up to 16 Mb |
| LargeBinary(length=16777216) | LONGBLOB | Up to 4 Gb |